# Mobile Push not sent from Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I'm trying to send mobile push notification from Journey Builder, but it does not send any messages, although it functions properly with Mobile Push Lists, so the certificates are implemented properly.

In my Data Extension I have appropriate fields (Contact Key, Device Id, System Token, Platform):
[image]

Also on All Contacts list the contacts have the same values for the Device Id, System Token and Platform, active status and no opt-out:

[image]
[image]

Additionally, I have connected my Data Extension as an attribute group in Contact Builder.

Can you see any error why it doesn't work with Journey Builder, although it works well with Mobile Studio?

Comment: what type of push message are you sending, in app or push?

Comment: Push notification from journey builder.

Comment: Did you have any success with this? It appears I might be facing the same issues